# Web Scraping of a an internet site that is running a long test

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape an internet speed test site, and not able to get the data. I tried few sites that needs a click but could not find the proper place in the html page with the button. So I switched to a site that does not require a button click. But now I do not get the result back, even though I waited 60 seconds for the test to finish. When I inspect the HTML in the browser, after the test is done, I see the results, but it is not included in the html page downloaded, and I do not understand why. Here is the code I used (Python):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

URL = 'https://www.bezeq.co.il/internetandphone/internet/speedtest/'
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get(URL)
sleep(60) # give time for the test to finish
page0 = driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

When I inspect the HTML code on the site I can see the results (upload 9501, download 86.19) but it is not showing in the 'page0' I get from the driver.

```
    <div class="bezeq-results">
   <div class="speed download">
      <div class="title">מהירות הורדה</div>
      <div class="value">86.19 Mb/s</div>
   </div>
   <div class="speed upload">
      <div class="title">מהירות העלאה</div>
      <div class="value">9501 Kb/s</div>
   </div>
   <div class="info"><span class="company"><span class="value">ITC NG ltd</span> <span class="hebrew">:ספק</span></span><span class="ping">Ping: <span class="value">30ms</span></span><span class="ip">IP: <span class="value">185.108.81.221</span></span></div>
   <button class="btn">בדוק שוב</button>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I get the data?

Comment: You want to scrape the internet speed test for what purpose? if you want to get to know your connection speed you can use `speedtest-cli`

Comment: I have some internet problems so I want to run the test every half an hour and get a log of the speed, to see when does it slows down. In any case, my question is also in order to learn how to handle web scraping for such cases

Answer (score 0):

I found out the data is in an Iframe. So I had to do a request to get the data from the Iframe and got the data